Connected components of a family of polynomials: A deformation theory approach?
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued polynomial function.  Consider the family of real algebraic sets:
$$
V_c = f^{-1}(c), \quad c \in (-1,1).
$$
I am interested in determining how the connected components of $V_c$ change as $c$ varies. I might have some partial information in the case $c = 0$.
Consider the morphism of schemes:
$$
\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R[ x_1, \cdots, x_d, c] / (f -c) \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R
$$
Note: I want to restrict the parameter, $c$, to be between only $-1$ and $1$. However, I am not sure how to make sense of it since $(-1,1)$ is not an open subset of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb R$. Moreover, the morphism must satisfy some special properties, I believe, but let's ignore that detail for now.
Naively, I am thinking of this problem through the lens of deformation theory. We would like to deform the set $V_0$ infinitesimally and observe how its topological properties change. Then, we'd like to argue that the change in topological properties remains stable as long as $c$ has the same parity and is less than one. My initial numerical investigations seem to suggest this is true.
Can we use techniques in deformation theory to tackle this problem?
Naively, I would expect to compute $H^0$ associated to the morphism above and see how the rank of $H^0$ depends on $c$. However, I don't know enough technical details to say if this is the right approach.
Note: My problem has some special structure. Write the coordinates of $ \mathbb R^{n_1 + \cdots + n_d}$ as $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_d)$. The polynomial $f : \mathbb{R}^{n_1 + \cdots + n_d} \to \mathbb{R}$ is of the form:
$$
f(x_1, \cdots,x_d) = \prod_{k=1}^d f_k(x_k)
$$
Here each $f_k$ is a real-valued polynomial

By the way, $\mathcal{O}$ is not an open subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ - the open subschemes of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ are the complements of finitely many closed points, which $\mathcal{O}$ is not.

@KReiser Silly me. I have edited the question and replaced $\mathcal{O}$ with $\text{Spec} , \mathbb{R}$. But if I want to restrict $c$ to be an indeterminate that is only between $-1$ and $1$, how should I proceed?

@user82261 As far as I know there is no way in algebraic geometry (at least classically or scheme theoretically) to describe something like an interval. Generally this brings you into the realm of semi-algebraic geometry. On another note, if you're mostly interested in the topology of these schemes (as opposed to the individual isomorphism classes) you might just want to look at Morse theory, which is squarely under the heading of differential topology.

@TabesBridges That was my thought as well. However, Morse Theory seems to deal with the topology of a fixed ‘space’ (compact manifold etc.) by studying critical points of Morse functions. Here I essentially have a family of varying ‘spaces.’ So I wasn’t quite sure how to proceed.
